# Changing the font size

Tags: fontsize

When I change my first line from

```
\documentclass{report}
```

to

```
\documentclass{report}[12pt]
```

the font size of the resulting pdf doesn't increase. 
I am using `pdflatex` to compile tex to pdf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have the order wrong, it should be `\documentclass[12pt]{report}`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple syntax error